# Java: select from collection only elements of provided type

Tags: java, collections

I have a collection of elements of type B and C, which all extends A. I need to filter the collection to get elements of only B type.

Is there any way to do it except:

```
for (A a : initCollection) {
  if (a instanceof B) {
    newCollection.add(a)?
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you like the way it's made now?

Comment: You can also wait for Java7. This can be done shorter with [closures](http://javac.info), I imagine.

Answer (score 11):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) was alluded to in other answers, but not the specific solution, which is even simpler than people realize:

```
Iterable<B> onlyBs = Iterables.filter(initCollection, B.class);
```

It's simple and clean, does the right thing, only creates a single instance and copies nothing, and doesn't cause any warnings.

(The `Collections2.filter()` method does not have this particular overload, though, so if you really want a `Collection`, you'll have to provide `Predicates.instanceOf(B.class)` and the resulting collection will still sadly be of type `Collection<A>`.)

Comment: Be aware that with this solution, every time you iterate over overBs, the filtering logic will be executed. This can either be a good thing (if initCollection is updated and you want onlyBs to reflect the changes) or a bad thing (if you are expecting a copy, or pass onlyBs to some code that iterates over it many times). If you want a copy, just create a collection from the output of filter().

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything wrong with doing it as per your example. However, if you want to get fancy you could use Google's [Guava library](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html), specifically the `Collections2` class, to do a functional-style filtering on your collection. You get to provide your own predicate, which can of course do the `instanceof` thing.

```
Collection<Object> newCollection = Collections2.filter(initCollection, new Predicate<Object>() { 
    public boolean apply(Object o) {
        return !(o instanceof String);
    } 
});
```

Comment: all right, thanks. The same can be accompllishen by apache's commons-collections library

Comment: @glaz: it's only not generic. Guava (Google Collections) is. I wouldn't miss parameterized types.

Comment: I'm a big fan of google collections. But I don't see any advantages which google collections can give in this particular example. There will be one more project-dependency, more lines of code, more complicated code, almost sure that it'll be slower. And no any pros.

Comment: @Roman: I mentioned Guava only as an alternative; it's mostly a matter of taste. But you may be surprised to note that the Guava solution offers *better* performance. The OP's solution creates a new data structure with a subset of the original data; that's a lot of `new`s and work for the garbage collector. `Collections2`, on the other hand, offers a view into the original collection, i.e. no new data structure (apart from a small fixed-cost support data structure, I'd wager). This is a nice example for the greater efficiency of functional programming.

Comment: @Carl Smotricz: could you attach a code example (or at least mention methods from Collection2) which do the things you've described, please?

Comment: Sure. From `Collections2.filter()` javadoc: "Returns the elements of `unfiltered` that satisfy a predicate. **The returned collection is a live view of unfiltered**; changes to one affect the other." (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Roman: I was so free to edit it in. It has however one disadvantage. The returned collection can't be generified to the desired type.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for the edit! You realized I was too lazy ;) Are you German, by chance? s/I was so free to edit/I took the liberty of editing/

Comment: @Carl, no, I'm Holland-born. Only my last name is German (grand-grandfather was German). Thanks for the language lesson though, much appreciated.

Comment: @BalusC right, the returned collection has the wrong type. see my answer for the solution to that.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no plain way to do it without adding code to classes A, B, and C.
The real question is: Why do you need to filter out elements of a specific type? It goes against the very idea of sub-typing in OOP.

Comment: why it goes so? I've got a collection of super type, which of course can have different subtype instances. Now I want to have exact class. Why not? where is mistake?

Comment: It's not a mistake. While an OO purist might say that for whatever manipulation you want to do, make every object in the main collection implement a method to do it (with the higher-level objects implementing a noop method) that takes a performance hit often enough that doing what you are asking is quite frequent.

Comment: +1  The desire to do this seems like a code smell to me.  There are circumstances where it might be the right approach, but I think in most cases, changing the design would be a better option.

Comment: @glaz666: If you have to filter the sub-types from the super-type, it insinuates that the super-type is ill-designed. It's not always the case, but in many situations the problems can be solved without using reflection: E.g., using the Visitor pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create new collection you can remove odd elements from existing one:

```
Iterator<A> it = initCollection.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()){
   if (it.next() instanceof C) {
      it.remove();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd add this in case anyone finds it.

You can do this using pure Java 8 and its `Stream`s.

```
List<B> filtered = listOfA.stream()
    .filter(a -> a instanceof B)
    .map(a -> (B) a)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```